# React Native Flatlist with radio buttons works slow

Tags: react-native, optimization, react-native-flatlist

I have flatlist with custom radio buttons implementaion, but when i tap on flatlist item it waits about second before changes to active button. I tried to useCallback with my *renderItem* and *itemKeyExtractor* functions but it doesnt help me.

Here is the code of my screen component:

```
export const PickOrganizationScreen = (props) => {
  const { navigation, setOrganization, loadProcedureProviders, items, isLoading, procedureId, organizationId } = props;

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(()=>{loadProcedureProviders(procedureId);},[loadProcedureProviders, procedureId])
  );

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
    <OrganizationItem
      title={item.Title}
      checked = {item.Id === organizationId}
      onPress={() => {
        setOrganization(item.Id, item.Title);
      }}
    />);
  };

  const itemKeyExtractor = (item) => item.Id;

  return (
    isLoading ? (
      <Spinner />
    ) : (
      items.length > 0 ? (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.paragraph}>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{I18n.t('pickOrganization')}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.alertMessage}>
            <View style={styles.alertIcon}>
              <Icon name="info" width={32} height={32} fill={Colors.primaryRed} />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.alertText}>{I18n.t('pickOrganizationToRegisterService')}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <FlatList
            data = {items}
            renderItem = {renderItem}
            keyExtractor = {itemKeyExtractor}
            extraData={organizationId}
          />

          <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
            <ScreenButton
              title={I18n.t('goToRegister')}
              onPress={ () => {
                navigation.navigate('ServiceSummary');
              }}/>
          </View>
        </View>
        ) : (
          <NotFound extraText={I18n.t('notFoundExtra')}/>
        )
     )
  );
};
```

Here is the code of flatlist item component:

```
export const OrganizationItem = ({title, checked, onPress}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.itemIcon}>
          { checked ? (
              <Icon name="radio-button-on" width={16} height={16} fill={Colors.primaryRed} />
            ) :
            (
              <Icon name="radio-button-off" width={16} height={16} fill={Colors.gray} />
            )
          }
        </View>
        <View style={styles.itemText}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try memoizing OrganizationItem. Does the onPress in OrganizationItem change the items object ? If so, it will re-render the whole Flatlist even when one small change is made. If you memoize, the components memoized won't rerender unless the props passed to it changes.

```
   export const OrganizationItem = React.memo(({title, checked, onPress}) => {
   return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
  <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
    <View style={styles.itemIcon}>
      { checked ? (
          <Icon name="radio-button-on" width={16} height={16} fill={Colors.primaryRed} />
        ) :
        (
          <Icon name="radio-button-off" width={16} height={16} fill={Colors.gray} />
        )
      }
    </View>
       <View style={styles.itemText}>
         <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   );
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it did not help. OrganizationItem doesnt produce any state change, onPress used to navigate to the next screen, as i mentioned above onPress={ () => {navigation.navigate('ServiceSummary');} }

Comment: there's an onPress inside OrganisationItem's TouchableOpacity as well in your code.  `<OrganizationItem
      title={item.Title}
      checked = {item.Id === organizationId}
      onPress={() => {
        setOrganization(item.Id, item.Title);
      }}
    />`
this is mutating the organisationId which is making the whole screen component re-render.

Comment: I suggest you use react-redux for cases where states need to accessed and edited from multiple components.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But i use redux actually in my app (setOrganization and organizationId comes from HOC as props). Cant figure out how to update organizationId and use it then in my Flatlist to point, what item is selected and not to re-render all screen component.